# Angular 2 Routing Tutorial Failing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When going through the [tutorial routing section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) the console says there is no `@angular/router/bundles` now, there is a `router-deprecated` package installed, which does have such a folder, but switching to it in app.routes.ts doesn't help either.

How should it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a step you might have missed when going through the tutorial. The tutorial uses the latest version of angular2-router which `"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1"` which does not have `bundles` folder like other angular2 repos.

Confirm that your package.json file has dependencies as stated on [guide page.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/npm-packages.html)
Then change your system.config.js file to be same as the one on [quickstart page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

Comment: I had `-alpha.4`, maybe that made a difference. Also then, I had problems with `Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property` until I added importing of `[RouterOutlet, RouterLink, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]` and put them in directives, as explained in one of the 8 questions on SO on the same error.

Comment: Ended up removing some and staying just with `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` and it still works. Probably had another problem somewhere...